How to omit red parentheses highlighting in .txt files in Visual Studio Code?
When writing a .txt file in VSC, a stand-alone parenthesis will be highlighted to mark that it's missing its opposite. How can I disable the highlighting?


Why would you have a string of text in a .txt file with an orphaned ( or )?

@spikey_richie I wanted to do a listing like this:

Element 1
Element 2
...
But the highlighting it's very distracting other that looking bad


You will need to disable editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled setting.
If you want to enable it in other types of files, you'll need to disable it only for plaintext type manually in settings.json file:
"[plaintext]": {
  "editor.bracketPairColorization.enabled": false
}

